# Inner Products in Principal Component Analysis in R

Tags: r, pca

For this, I am using the banknote data in R given by `data(banknote)`, which shows measurements of 200 Swiss banknotes. My data matrix is called `X`, and I have performed PCA by `pca.banknote<-prcomp(X)`.

I am trying to show that the inner product between each observation `X[i,]` and Principal Component Loading 3 given by `pca.banknote$rot[,3]` is the same as the 3rd PC scores given by `pca.banknote$x[,3]`.

I have attempted:

```
all.equal(as.matrix(X[,])%*%banknote.pca$rot[,3], as.matrix(banknote.pca$x[,3]), check.attributes=FALSE)
```

but this simply gives a mean difference of 1, i.e. they are not equal.

Do I need to change the format of one of these to a vector/data frame etc for this to work? Or any ideas at all as to where the issue is?

Any feedback would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From a quick check I can say that the two quantities are not the same:
`pca.banknote$x[1,3] = 0.272243` while
`(as.matrix(banknote) %*% pca.banknote$rotation[,3])[1,1] = 239.4763`.

Comment: @Cettt I got the same thing. However, I have been asked to **show** that they are indeed the same! A hint has been given as to perhaps use `scale()` if that changes anything?

Comment: well they are not the same.
Either you misunderstood the exercise or whoever wrote the exercise was mistaken.
It is definetly not an issue of formats or anything.